# Deviation of Speed

Tags: c

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float v = 42/0.56, t = 0.56,
    bv, // Speed Error
    bs = +2&&-2, // Distance Error
    s = 42, // Distance
    bt = +0.06&&-0.06,// Time Error
    x,y,z;

    v = v*(18/5); //change unit from m/s to km/hr
    printf("Speed of Ferrari FF = %.3f km/hr",v);

    x = (bv)/v ;
    y = (bs)/s ;
    z = (bt)/t ;

    x = sqrt( y*y + z*z ) ;
    bv = v * x ;
    bv = bv * 18/5 ;
    printf("\nDeviation of Speed = %.3f km/hr",bv);

}
```

[image]

The Question is in Thai language so I type all the thing question give me in float by unit m,s,m/s. I'm confused as to what I did wrong here.

this is the question ( translate )
From camera that capture the car, Ferrari FF move from point A to B use 0.56 second. From the picture, Find out Speed of the car in Km/Hr and Deviation of Speed in Km/Hr.
Given Deviation of Distance +2 and -2   ,    Deviation of Time +0.06 and -0.06. The Speed we got from (1) Equation that v (m/s) and Deviation calculated from (2) Equation by bs is Deviation of Distance and bt is Deviation of Time. Use Math Library to find the exponential and square root

[image]

Comment: `bs = +2&&-2` is `bs = 1`- I doubt that is what you had in mind with that line of code

Comment: am I coding it wrong ? It has 2 values which is +2 and -2 because it's error of distance

Comment: What is `+2&&-2` supposed to do? Read about the `&&` operator in your C text book. Also you don't initialize `bv` before using it.

Comment: Ohhhh Thanks! Now I need to find what to replace it.

Comment: Also don't use integer constants in a floating point calculation. `18/5` gives 3, not 3.6. As was foretold in the first chapters of your favourite C book...

Comment: `+2&&-2` I think I've understood what you want. `bs` is the distance error which can vary between -2 and +2 meters. `bt` is the time error which can vary between -0.06 and + 0.06 seconds. You job is probably to calculate the speed error which is a function of the time error and the distance error. You should translate the text of the assignment into english and put that into the question.

Comment: Ok I will try to translate it as best as I can.

Comment: I'm done translating it.

Comment: I think you should try bs = (2 - (-2)) / 2. Same for bt.

Comment: @PtitXav `bs = (2 - (-2)) / 2` hu?? That's a constant value which is 2. `2 - (-2)) / 2` = `2 + 2) / 2` = `4 / 2` = `2`.

Comment: I assume that it is a deviation so I take interval between -2 and + 2 divided by 2. May be the division Is to much but the difference should be used in both cases.

Comment: `x = 5` in C and in mathematics are very different things! Also, you can not assign a value and a deviation (5 +/- 1) to a variable in C, that's simply not how that works. You can use two variables (min/max values) instead to express the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making two mistakes in your code:

- Declaration of error margins
- Ignorance of integer and floating point arithmetic

Let's explain both of them:

- Declaration of error margins

I have the impression that you are trying to say something like:

```
Value_1 - Value_2 must be located in interval [-bs, +bs]
```

The point is, in programming languages, there is only one way to write this:

```
ABS(Value_1 - Value_2) <= bs
```

Where:

- ABS() is the function, calculating the absolute value
- bs must be a single number (like `2` in your case)

Now the second point:

- Ignorance of integer and floating point arithmetic

Computers have two ways of working with numbers: integer arithmetic and floating point arithmetic.
When you are working with integer numbers, then the computer automatically assumes you are doing integer arithmetic (which means that the computer will round your results to integer numbers). As a result:

- 1 / 3 = 0 (0.333... rounded to integer equals 0)
- 3 / 3 = 1
- 5 / 3 = 1 (1.666... rounded to integer equals 1)

So, if you declare a number like `18/5`, that will automatically be recognised as `3`.

If you want floating point arithmetic, then you must tell this to your computer, but don't make this mistake:

```
(double)(18/5)
```

This is also 3, because first you do `18/5`, which is considered integer arithmetic, and only then you convert to floating point. No, you should do something like:

```
((double)18)/5
```

Here you clearly say that 18 is to be handled as a floating point number, so floating point arithmetic should be used, and the result will be 3.6, but be careful:
**There's a big chance that the value is NOT 3.6!**
The reason for that is that computers are having accuracy problems, and 18/5 might be calculated as 3.5999999999. Therefore, always foresee an error margin while working with floating points.

Answer (score 1):

There are unnecessary complications in your code. This task is easily completed by setting variables as described in the problem and performing simple straightforward calculations. The only complication is that the formula does not give v directly. It gives v/v. So the code below calculates v/v first and then multiplies by v to get v.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    /*  The vehicle traverses a distance of 42 meters in .56 seconds so set s
        to 42 and t to .56.
    */
    float s = 42;
    float t = .56;

    //  The "deviation" in distance is ±2 meters, so set ds to 2.
    float ds = 2;

    //  The "deviation" in time is ±.06 seconds, so set dt to .06.
    float dt = .06;

    //  Calculate the speed and print it in km/hour.
    float v = s/t;
    printf("Speed is %.3f km/hr.\n", v/1000*3600);

        /*  Note that we print with a newline after a line of text, not before.
            Standard output is commonly line buffered, meaning that a newline
            causes output to be sent.  Since we want a line to be sent when we
            print it, not later, we end lines with a newline character.
        */

    //  Calculate ds/s and dt/t.
    float ds_s = ds/s;
    float dt_t = dt/t;

    //  Calculate dv/v according to the given formula.
    float dv_v = sqrtf(ds_s*ds_s + dt_t*dt_t);

    //  Calculate dv from dv/v.
    float dv = dv_v * v;

    //  Print the "deviation" in speed in km/hr.
    printf("Deviation of speed is %.3f.\n", dv/1000*3600);
}
```